# Each integer is either coloured red, yellow or green. Show that there always exists a, b, c such that a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c are Monochromatic

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So basically, this is an olympiad level question from the movie "A brilliant young mind" or in America, it's known as "X+Y"

> Each integer is either coloured red, yellow or green. Show that there always exists a, b, c such that a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c are Monochromatic i.e. Of the same colour.

Some people have suggested using the [Van der Waerden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem) but I can't just solve it, please help!

Thank you!

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22795/the-tough-one-from-a-brilliant-young-mind-2014